# How to get sign-in user information after getting the successful login from OneDrive API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onedrive

I am fetching the files and folders from Onedrive, after successful login from the OneDrive API and saving all files and folders in local directive. After login from the API I want to fetch the sign-in user information and save it in database

GraphServiceClient graphClientUser = new GraphServiceClient(

"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/",

new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                           async (requestMessageForUser) => {

requestMessageForUser.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", AccessToken);

}));

var currentUser = await graphClientUser.Me.Request().GetAsync();

Comment: You can't do it and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: I have done for dropbox and google drive but not able to for OneDrive,I need it because I have to save the informations in the database.